# В PyCharn мигает белая строчка, из-за которой писать код нельзя

Tags: python, pycharm

Зашел недавно в PyCharm, нажал куда-то и появилась эта строчка мигающая. Когда пытаюсь писать буквы ничего не происходит и слышу звук ошибки винды. Не знаю как это убрать.

Фото проблемы:

[image]

Comment: Может `Alt` нажали, нет? )

Answer (score 4):

В PyCharm ну или в PhpStorm (привел те, которыми пользовался) клавиша <kbd>Insert</kbd> используется для переключения между режимами вставки и замены текста.

В режиме вставки, когда клавиша <kbd>Insert</kbd> неактивна, новый текст, который ты вводишь, вставляется перед существующим текстом. Если ты нажмешь клавишу Insert в этом режиме, то перейдешь в режим замены.

В режиме замены, когда клавиша <kbd>Insert</kbd> активна, новый текст, который ты вводишь, заменяет существующий текст, начиная с текущего положения курсора.

Использование клавиши <kbd>Insert</kbd> полезно, когда ты хочешь перезаписать существующий текст без необходимости удалять его вручную.

Comment: Но я всё ещё не уверен, что insert способен вызывать «звук ошибки винды»

Comment: а нажать на инсерт и послушать в разных режимах ввода не вариант?

Comment: Не вариант, потому что у меня нет винды) А под линуксом он у меня никаких звуков не издаёт

Comment: Проверил в PyCharm 2023.2 под Win10 - никаких посторонних звуков ни при замене ни при вставке нет, ввод не блокируется

Comment: Фух,спасибо за помощь.Помогли.Я и правда нажал insert случайно

Answer (score 1):

Судя по фото в вопросе, у вас включен плагин *IdeaVim*, который имитирует редактор Vim в PyCharm.

Чтобы его отключить, нажмите на его значок в слева внизу,
и в открывшемся меню нажмите на пункт "*✔ Enabled*":

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну вот, шутка про «бибикать и всё портить» оказалась не шуткой )